# How do i create a cookie for the first time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I want to create a cookie for storage for a post request but i am facing challlenges on what to understand

I tried creating a cookie class and a handle cookie method but the creation doesnt seem to work and it stops my login from working

Comment: can you add the code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving any data to local storage of the device you can use several solutions in flutter.

- the most basic solution is shared preferences. You can store primitive data types and String lists with this. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
- If you want to encrypt the storing data you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage.
- For storing more complex data you can use a library like hive. Hive provides features for storing model classes. https://pub.dev/packages/hive. Also, you can encrypt stored data by hive and flutter_secure_storage combination.
- As another option you can use sql database with sqflite plugin. https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite. If you are not going to manage really large amount of data, I recommend using hive instead of sqflite.

Especially for your problem I recommend flutter_secure_storage. It is a good option for storing simple and sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

To access the cookie you need the [cookie_jar](https://pub.dev/packages/cookie_jar) and [dio_cookie_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_cookie_manager) package and to use the cookie you need to store the cookie in fileStorage and to store, you need the documentsDirectory so you need the [path provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class WebService {    
  WebService();


  final dio = Dio();
  var cookieJar;

  Future<bool> setCookieJar() async {
    if (this.cookieJar == null) {
      try {
        Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        var cookieJar = PersistCookieJar(
            ignoreExpires: true,
            storage: FileStorage(appDocPath + "/.cookies/"));

        print('it is cookie    setCookieJar  ' + cookieJar.toString());
        dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));

        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        Exception("exception on cookie");
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

after adding these packages you can use the WebService class to inject the cookie to network package like [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).

and you can write your rest methods (get, post,....) inside the WebService as follows.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class WebService {    
  WebService();
  final dio = Dio();
  var cookieJar;

  Future<bool> setCookieJar() async {
    if (this.cookieJar == null) {
      try {
        Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        var cookieJar = PersistCookieJar(
            ignoreExpires: true,
            storage: FileStorage(appDocPath + "/.cookies/"));

        print('it is cookie    setCookieJar  ' + cookieJar.toString());
        dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));

        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        Exception("exception on cookie");
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

    Future<ServerResponse> getFunction() async {
    Response response;
    try {
      await setCookieJar();
      response = await dio.get(url);
    } catch (errorMessage) {
      print(errorMessage);
    }
    return ServerResponse(response);
  }
```

}

Before using the WebService class you must inject it as follows.
I am using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for injecting.

```
void main() async {
  return runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [Provider.value(value:WebService ())], child: const MyApp()));
}
```

Using:

```
var response = await Provider<WebService>.of(context,listen:false).getFunction();
```